# No data being sent from RaspberryPi IoTF Quickstart recipe

Tags: ibm-cloud, raspberry-pi2

I have a RaspberryPi2 running the Quickstart recipe following instructions on https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/recipes/raspberry-pi/

This includes installing the "quickstart" - grabbing the files from
curl -LO https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-raspberrypi/releases/download/1.0.2/iot_1.0-1_armhf.deb, installing via sudo dpkg -i iot_1.0-1_armhf.deb and then checking the service is running using "service iot status". The response is as expected
[ ok ] iot is running.
Next step - get the device id using: service iot getdeviceid
And I should be able to enter this on the web page mention above and see data.

The iotf page says:

> We are waiting for your device to send us a message
>
> The device ID you have entered is valid, but we are waiting for your
>   device to send us a message.
>
> Get your device to send us some valid data - we'll visualize it for
>   you

Some initial connection failures
but the last attempt passes and /var/log/system says:

> Jun 28 21:14:55 rasppi2 iot[2029]: Connecting to
>   ssl://XXXXX.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:8883 with client
>   Id: d:XXXXX:RaspberryPi2:
>   Jun 28 21:14:55 rasppi2 ntpd_intres[2135]: DNS 0.debian.pool.ntp.org -> 217.79.179.106
>   Jun 28 21:14:55 rasppi2 ntpd_intres[2135]: DNS 1.debian.pool.ntp.org ->
>   178.33.227.201
>   Jun 28 21:14:55 rasppi2 ntpd_intres[2135]: DNS 2.debian.pool.ntp.org -> 193.225.118.162
>   Jun 28 21:14:55 rasppi2 ntpd_intres[2135]: DNS 3.debian.pool.ntp.org -> 148.251.6.51
>   Jun 28 21:14:55 rasppi2 iot[2029]: Connection was successful
>   Jun 28 21:14:58 rasppi2 iot[2029]: Subscription succeeded

Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: Can you post some debug information?  It is hard to help you without some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like maybe you have stored the device registration info and are trying to connect with it rather than with quickstart?

Connecting to ssl://XXXXX.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:8883 with client Id: d:XXXXX:RaspberryPi2:

To use quickstart connection, I would expect the client ID to say quickstart.

Did you do the step in the recipe that included copying the registered device info into device.cfg file on the pi?
 If you are connected as a registered device then you can't use the quickstart realtime visualization webpage for a device that is connecting with a registered client ID.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  I did have a device.cfg file present from some previous work.  I uninstalled the package (sudo dpkg -P iot), reinstalled, and it worked.  I also needed to double-check my deviceId to make sure I was pointing to the right device.